# Ruby on Rails rendering failed signup attemp w/o changing the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello every one I am new at ruby on rails i just want to ask how to render a failed signup attempt w/o changing the URL and with validations?

Answer (score 0):

**A form to sign up new users-**

`app/views/users/new.html.erb`

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Adding an @user variable to the new action-**

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end
end
```

**A create action that can handle signup failure (but not success)-**

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**Code to add error message display to the signup form-**

`app/views/users/new.html.erb`

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  .
  .
  .
<% end %>
```